# What site should I ask a question about Chrome's memory usage on MacOs?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What site should I ask a question about Chrome's memory usage on MacOs?

I don't think it is on topic over here,
Possibly on Ask Different?
I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not on Web Apps.

[Super User](https://superuser.com) would seem to be appropriate. Since it's specifically about a Mac, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) may be a better option.